# $\frac{S_n}{n} \to -1 \ \ a.e.$, exercise from probability book

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm stuck with this exercise from Williams, probability with martingales.

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots $be independent random variables with $$P(X_n = n^2-1 )= \frac{1}{n^2}$$  $$P(X_n = -1 )= 1-\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Then if $S_n = X_1+ X_2, + \ldots + X_n$ we have $$\frac{S_n}{n} \to -1 \ \ a.e.$$

Any hint ?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(X_n \neq -1) < \infty$$ it follows from the Borel-Cantelli lemma that for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$ there exists $N = N(\omega)$ such that $$X_n(\omega)=-1 \qquad \text{for all} \, n \geq N.$$

Comment: You are faster, +1

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle :) Thanks.